# Why I am getting segmentation fault when I increase the value of elements of matrix in a matrix multiplication program in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, matrix-multiplication

Why I am getting segmentation fault when I increase the value of elements of matrix such as 11 20 10. Usually I am getting first row of resultant matrix as all 0s and second row of matrix correctly . Also sometimes it gives correct result . I don't know what is wrong with this code

Comment: Make sure you are not trying to access a memory that was not allocated, calling a function on an empty pointer could be the cause of the issue.
What does your stack trace say, you should be able to see what line is failing if you debug your code ?

Answer (score 1):

One potential problem is that it looks like the member variable `K` can change:

```
(data->B) = malloc((data->K)*sizeof(float*));
scanf("%d%d", &(data->K), &(data->N));
for ( i=0;i<(data->K);i++)
   ...
```

It is first initialized when setting up array `A`.  And then it is used to allocate the base array to hold the columns for `B`.  But then the next `scanf` could result in a value that is no longer the same as before (could result in memory overwrites).

Comment: I changed the code and I am taking now m,n as dimensions of first matrix and p,q as dimensions of second matrix but if now I do it with 2X2 matrix it gives answer but with 2 3 , 3 4 matrix it either gives segmentation fault or it may give 2 rows as 0s and one row correct . I am puzzled . Is my runner function correct ?

Comment: My segmentation fault is resolved but I am getting 0s in one or more rows of the matrix I don't know why ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you inverted these two lines,

```
(data->B) = malloc((data->K)*sizeof(float*));
scanf("%d%d", &(data->K), &(data->N));
```

So, you are using the previous value of **data->K**, so if your second matrix will be greater than your first, you'll then access memory not allocated -> **scanf("%f", &(data->B[i][j]))**